# JSON inserting array into object with same key name

Tags: javascript, json

```js
var arr = ['1', '2', '3']
var part = {}
var partContents = []

arr.map(function(i){
  partContents.push({ obj: i })
  part['text'] = partContents
})

console.log(part);
```

How can I make it to be separate arrays with same key name 'text' per object of loop instead of my code combining every object into only a single array?

Comment: Please, show the example of what you want to have in the end

Comment: BTW, JSON has nothing to deal with it

Comment: i want something like

{
  "text": [ { "obj": "1"} ],
"text": [ { "obj": "2"} ],
"text": [ { "obj": "3"} ]
}

Comment: what is the objective why do you want a structure like this? Its not feasible

Comment: But you can't. You can not have the same property ("text") multiple times. You can do either  `{ "text": [ { "obj": "1"} ], "text2": [ { "obj": "2"} ], "text3": [ { "obj": "3"} ] }` or  `[{ "text": [ { "obj": "1"} ] }, {"text": [ { "obj": "2"} ]}, {"text": [ { "obj": "3"} ] }]`. Both structures are smelly and bad. You should answer to @karthick 's question

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['1', '2', '3']
var part = []

arr.map(function(i){
  part.push({
    text: [{obj: i}]
  });
})

console.log(part);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Thanks!